# How to import Bootstrap JS with HTML5 reusable web components

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web-frontend

RESOLVED: see my solution in a comment

TL;DR: Can't get bootstrap's JS to trigger, suspect that I'm importing the JS scripts wrong

I've been trying to get Bootstrap to work properly with my custom reusable web components to work properly across all pages. (i.e.: my footer and header components)

Notably, I can't get the header nav, which collapses into a hamburger in a small screen, to trigger. I also can't get my modals to trigger on button click, but I could potentially pin this on not having other JS written for it. I doubt that carousels or any other dynamic elements would work due to this.

I've imported all relevant CSS (which seems to work), and am trying to also import the JS that the desired behavior depends on, but haven't had much luck.

Here is what I've been trying for my components/header.js file. This allows me to put  to any of my HTML files in the root folder, so that I can easily reuse without duplicate code.

```
headerTemplate.innerHTML = `
<style> 
    @import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css");
    @import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css");
</style>
<header>
    <script src=”https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js”></script>
    <script type=”text/javascript” src=”https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js”></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand nav-link active" href="index.html">Sample</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="listings.html">Listings</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="listings.html">Listings</a>
                    </li> 
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="listings.html">Listings</a>
                    </li>
               </ul>
               <div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal"> Login</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary onclick="location.href='settings.html'" type="submit">Settings</button> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Done</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
`;

class Header extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'closed' });

        shadowRoot.appendChild(headerTemplate.content);
    }
}

customElements.define('header-component', Header);
```

Comment: Erm, why you have two (v3.3.6 and v5.3.0) bootstrap JS loaded ? not sure it might cause bootstrap function conflict or not, try to remove the old (3.3.6) one and and only include the latest scripts (css and JS) from boostrap [website](https://getbootstrap.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved.

Turns out adding a shadow dom as a tutorial recommended me do was the fault in my stars.

These are the scripts that I ended up using in the HTML files I used my components in:

Did not need popper or anything

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <script src=”https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js”></script> 
    <script src=”https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js”></script>
    <script type=”text/javascript” src=”https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js”></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative to show you:

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="navbarContainer"></div>

    <script>
      fetch("navbar.html")
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((content) => {
          document.getElementById("navbarContainer").innerHTML = content;
        });
    </script>
    <script src="bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

navbar.html :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button
      class="navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-bs-toggle="collapse"
      data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a
            class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
            href="#"
            role="button"
            data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-expanded="false"
          >
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex" role="search">
        <input
          class="form-control me-2"
          type="search"
          placeholder="Search"
          aria-label="Search"
        />
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```